# how can i wirte linq to compair the year and month f

Tags: c#, mongodb, linq

I am trying to fetch record from my database year and month vise

I have write following linq

```
Connection cn = new Connection();

IMongoDatabase db = cn.ConnectionString();

var collection = db.GetCollection<HolidayListModel>("Holiday");

var filter = Builders<HolidayListModel>.Filter.Eq("business_id", businessid);

try
{
    var obj = collection.Find(filter).ToListAsync();

    if (obj != null && obj.Result != null)
    {
        if (month == "All")
        {
            holidaylist = obj.Result.Where(x => DateTime.Parse(x.date).Year == selectedyear).OrderBy(x => DateTime.Parse(x.date)).Select(x => new HolidayListModel()
            {
                _id = x._id,
                business_id = x.business_id,
                festival = x.festival,
                date = x.date,
                day = x.day
            }).ToList();
        }
        else
        {
            holidaylist = (from x in obj.Result where (( x.date  == month )) select x).ToList();
        }
```

Here with lambda expression I got the data year vise using query expression I can't find a way to fetch data using year and month

Can someone guide me how can I write linq for this problem

Comment: from x in obj.Result where (( DateTime.Parse(x.date).Month== month && DateTime.Parse(x.date).Year==year )) select x

Comment: i have tried this one but give me 0 result                                
 holidaylist = (from x in obj.Result where ((DateTime.Parse(x.date).Month.ToString() == month && DateTime.Parse(x.date).Year == selectedyear)) select x).ToList();

Answer (score 1):

This is usually done simply by using a start/end value; so `foo.Year == selectedYear` or `foo.date == month` becomes simply `foo >= @start && foo < @end` (the end is usually exclusive, so for a "year" check, that would be 1 Jan of the *next* year; for a "month" check it would be the 1st of the *next* month; this means that *times* in the last day are still always treated correctly).

If you are storing your dates in mongodb as strings that are ISO 8601 or similar, you could also do the same thing simply with string comparisons, without any "parse" logic.